# How delete not selection Base image, Small etc

Tags: magento

```
$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'FN244403');
$product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'FN229437');
$product1ID = $product1->getId();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` WHERE `entity_id` = '$product1ID' 

LIMIT 1";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
echo $path = $rows[0]['value'];
   echo "Edited sku is ".$product1->getSku()." ".$product1->getImage()." ".$product1-

>getThumbnail()." ".$product2->getImage();
echo " asdasd ".Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product' .trim($rows[0]['value']);  
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product1->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product' .trim

($rows[0]['value']), array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false); 
$product1->save();
```

I am adding product images such as Small image, Base image, Thumbnail. How I can delete second lost image which not selected as Small image, Base image, Thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [Magento programmatically remove product images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709496/magento-programmatically-remove-product-images)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($collection as $product){
   if ($product->getId()){
      $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
      $items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());
      foreach($items as $item){
         view elements of $item array
         print_r($item);
         if($item[] not check ){
            $mediaApi->remove($product->getId(), $item['file']);
         }
      }
   }
}
```